bash script replace credentials in json file
I have json file like this:
{
  "sdpSemantics": "unified-plan",
  "iceServers": [
    {
      "urls": "stun:1.1.1.1:3478"
    },
    {
      "urls": "turn:2.2.2.2:3478",
      "username": "1717583725:test",
      "credential": "9SW0KmmpmF4FV4yYj8O9zADRWFw="
    }
  ]
}

bash script:
#!/bin/bash
turn_secret=3fdcf0ff6d9e0b4a7c9bc250d814d33a7b23325d529f4f6cfc4ec655359540d7
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
future_timestamp=$((current_timestamp + 86400))
username="${future_timestamp}:test"
credential=$(echo -n "$username" | openssl sha1 -hmac "$turn_secret" -binary | base64)

# Strings:
jq --arg u "${username}" '.username = $u' rtc_config.json > "tmp" && mv "tmp" rtc_config.json

# Integers:
jq --arg c "${credential}" '.credential = $c' rtc_config.json > "tmp" && mv "tmp" rtc_config.json

it only creates new lines not replacing...


It's unclear what you want to replace. There is an array with some entries. Do you, for example, want to replace all those entries with a new entry that holds your data,  do you want to append a new entry to the array, or do you want to match a username somehow and replace only that entry?  Please don't post images of text.

Hi! It would be best if you posted your actual output as text, and added your expected output.

And don't post images of text.

Looks like you want to update the object in the array that has the credentials. You'll need to work a little harder:
jq --arg u "newUser" --arg c "newCred" '
    .iceServers |= map(
        if has("username")
        then (.username = $u | .credential = $c)
        else .
        end
    )
' file.json > modified.json

outputs
{
  "sdpSemantics": "unified-plan",
  "iceServers": [
    {
      "urls": "stun:1.1.1.1:3478"
    },
    {
      "urls": "turn:2.2.2.2:3478",
      "username": "newUser",
      "credential": "newCred"
    }
  ]
}


On the right-hand side of |=, . is the current value of the left-hand side.
Inside the map() function, . is the current array element.
jq 1.7, else . is the default "false" branch and can be omitted.


Supposing you want to udpate the iceServer array element corresponding to the given username with a new timestamp and a new credential string:
jq  --arg username "$username" \
    --arg timestamp "$timestamp" \
    --arg credentials "$credentials" '
    .iceServers | map(
        select( .username // empty | endswith(":" + $username) ) +=
        {
            username: ($timestamp + ":" + $username),
            credential: $credentials
        }
    )' file

This would update the username and credential values of any element of the iceServers array that have a username value ending in : followed by the given username.   Entries that don't match this criterion (the wrong username, or no username key at all) will not be modified.
Note that we keep the username and timestamp separate. Would you want to provide them as a single :-delimited username string, you would extract the actual name in the jq expression, possibly by using sub(), like this:
jq  --arg username "$username" \
    --arg credentials "$credentials" '
    .iceServers | map(
        select( .username // empty | endswith($username | sub(".*:";"")) ) +=
        {
            username: $username,
            credential: $credentials
        }
    )' file

If you don't want to pass credentials as an argument on jq's command line, consider reading them from the environment instead.  E.g. if you have a MY_CREDENTIALS environment variable:
jq  --arg username "$username" '
    .iceServers | map(
        select( .username // empty | endswith($username | sub(".*:";"")) ) +=
        {
            username: $username,
            credential: $ENV.MY_CREDENTIALS
        }
    )' file

You could do a similar thing for the username string.

I'd recommend using $ENV.username rather than passing the secrets on the command line (which on most systems is public). (but then again, AFAIK, there's no way to use openssl mac safely in that regard).

@StéphaneChazelas I'll add that as an alternative approach.
